# Problem installing Zoo Tycoon 2: Ultimate Collection

Tags: installation

I am getting this error when attempting to install Zoo Tycoon 2: Ultimate Collection on Windows 7. Anyone see this error before? I don't think I even have a drive F:

[image]

Comment: Are you installing off a CD drive, or a folder on a regular hard drive? And, pardon for the next question, is this an original software, or a copied copy?

Comment: Installing off a CD. It is a new original copy from the store. Another odd thing is The disk isnt even showing up in my computer. In order to get the installer running I have to restart the computer and it will only pop up on the first insert (Still wont show up in my computer by the other disks though.)

Comment: Does that particular file exist on the CD?

Comment: Yea I think so. take a look: http://imgur.com/Kthnu

Comment: your CD might be damaged - try to read it from a drive with better error correction capabilities. Hopefully you have made a copy of your original CD after buying, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

What drive letter is your CD mapped to?

At any rate, this looks like it may be a corrupt CD. I'd try copying EVERYTHING to the HD. If it succeeded (i.e., no error reading that particular file), try running setup.exe from your HD and see if it installs.